# Multiple selection UISegmentedControl in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement a UISegmentedControl that supports multiple selections as described in the comment below. However, I don't know how to create a UILabel with rounded edges and don't understand why a UILabel is used as container for the UIButtons?

Any help is highly appreciated!

> One way to do this, which I have done in shipping apps, is to use a UILabel with rounded
>   edges and put rectangular UIButtons inside. This way you can get the rounded edges for the 
>   combined control. Enjoy. – Damien Del Russo Feb 13 at 7:03

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to arrange the butons in a row and add Imageview over them (Imageview will overlap the button still the buttons are clickable.) then u can replace the Images on button clicks u should use Images such type that its should show which button is selected.